# iOS 13 / Swift 5: SearchController SearchBar expands when editing ends

Tags: ios, uikit, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller, swift5

I'm facing an issue with UISearchBar (XCode 11, iOS 13, Swift 5) inside ContainerView in a UITableView. There I created a UIView (searchView) and a sortView next to each other, so that the user can search and sort the results.

No problem so far, but when I end searching by tapping the cancel button of the searchbar, the searchbar expands to the full screen width and overlaps the sortView.

[Situation before activating search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IMFO.png)

[Situation with active search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cISGg.png)

[Wrong behaviour after deactivating search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEkuS.png)

How is it possible to keep the searchbar inside its superview (searchView)?

I've already set some constraints to do that but no success.

See some code, too:

```
func viewDidLoad() {
     ...

    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "SR durchsuchen ..."
    searchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).title = "Ende"
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self

    searchView.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)

    ...
    }


override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    self.searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()

}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

    self.searchController.definesPresentationContext = false
    self.searchController.isActive = false

}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let searchTextField = self.searchController.searchBar.searchTextField
    searchTextField.textColor = UIColor(named: "searchFieldTextColor")
    searchTextField.leftView?.tintColor = UIColor(named: "searchFieldTextColor")

    searchController.searchBar.frame.size.width = searchView.frame.size.width
    searchController.searchBar.frame.size.height = searchView.frame.size.height

}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {

    searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: searchView.frame.width, height: searchView.frame.height)
    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()

    let margins = searchView.layoutMarginsGuide
    searchController.searchBar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    searchController.searchBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    searchController.searchBar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    searchController.searchBar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call these methods as UISearchControllerDelegate:

```
func didPresentSearchController(_ searchController: UISearchController)
    {
        searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 266, height: searchController.searchBar.frame.size.height)
    }

func didDismissSearchController(_ searchController: UISearchController)
    {
        searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 266, height: searchController.searchBar.frame.size.height)
    }
```